# Cannot get dependency to run in Intellij: UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, jvm, gurobi

I have a Play framework application in Intellij to which I am trying to add Gurobi (an ILP optimizer) and have been running into some problems.  I have followed all of the instructions for installing Gurobi from their website.

In Intellij, I have added Gurobi to a /lib folder in the project, and it resolves all the symbols in the code OK, the code compiles, and I can run the application. I added Gurobi to the java library path by adding this to the JVM arguments to the run configuration:

-Djava.library.path=/opt/gurobi605/linux64/lib

I have also added 4 environment variables to the run configuration:

```
GUROBI_HOME="/opt/gurobi605/linux64"
PATH="${PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/bin"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/lib"
GUROBI_LICENCE="/home/mcmellawat/gurobi.lic"
```

I have also added these environment variables to the .bashrc file per Gurobi instructions, though I'm not sure it matters.

Despite all this, I am getting the following error when trying to instantiate the first Gurobi object (GRBEnv to be specific) in my code:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/gurobi605/linux64/lib/libGurobiJni60.so: libgurobi60.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have verified that this file does indeed exist in /opt/gurobi605/linux64/lib (it is actually a link to another file).  What could be causing it to not be found?

Answer (score 0):

The Gurobi FAQ (41) contains instructions how to use the Java interface from a development environment (e.g. Eclipse):
http://www.gurobi.com/support/faqs

1) You need to include gurobi.jar in your project (e.g. in your Build Path)

2) Make sure that the environment variable PATH (Windows) or LD_LIBRARY_PATH (Linux) contains the correct library folder.

- On Windows this is by default the `bin` folder of the Gurobi installation (e.g. gurobi60.dll and gurobi65.dll)
- On Linux this is by default the `lib` folder of the Gurobi installation (e.g. libgurobi60.so  and libGurobiJni60.so)